# Facebook API v2.1 - Does invitable_friends API need to enter the review process?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I've been reading through the [invitable_friends API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends) and it states under Permissions that "Access to the user_friends permission requires review of your app before it can be used by non-developers."

In contrast to this, the [Permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1) states that "If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers."

Can anyone confirm that if we are building a Canvas Facebook Game and trying to use the invitable_friends API whether we need to go through the review process or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm not a Facebook employee, I can't "confirm" this, but the review guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review says that

> You **do not** need to go through Login Review if your app requests these three basic permissions:
>   * public_profile
>   * user_friends
>   * email

So, I guess the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends#readperms are not correct.

I filed a bug report under https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1528594254021404/ Feel free to subscribe to get an official statement from Facebook (but don't expect this too soon :-/).

Comment: It looks like Facebook have acknowledged this is a bug in their docs. Hopefully should get a resolution shortly as to which documentation is correct.

Comment: Wow, that was fast :-)